# How can I remove files containing whitespace recursively?

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

I'm having some trouble with this command under bash in Ubuntu:

```
rm $(find . -name "*.exe")
```

My aim is to remove, recursively, all files ending in `.exe`. But some files have white spaces and this breaks the command.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.exe" -exec rm -f '{}' +
```

This has [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) format the command and arguments, and it carefully avoids mangling the names (by passing each one as a separate argument to `rm`).  The '+' means "do as many as you can reasonably in one execution of `rm`".

Comment: `find(1)` has the `-delete` action (maybe just GNU find only) which will save all the subprocesses and cumbersome command line options. `find . -name '*.exe' -delete`

Comment: @camh: follow the link to the POSIX documentation; `-delete` is not included.  It is in GNU `find`; the question is for Linux; so it is possible to use `-delete`.  However, all the world is not Linux, and a portable answer maybe of use.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output from `find` into `xargs`, specifying that only newlines should be considered as delimiters between filenames:

```
find -name '*.exe' | xargs -d \\n rm
```

The more portable way to do this is to use the null character as the delimiter:

```
find -name '*.exe' -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm
```

See `find`'s manpage for an example that does this.

Another option is to use the command you used, but to set bash's internal argument delimiter to newlines-only:

```
IFS=$'\n'; rm $(find . -name "*.exe");
```

Here the `$'...'` quoting construct is used to create a newline character.  This approach will be less resilient in the case of a long list of filenames than will using `xargs`.

Comment: There's no real point in using anything other than the `-print0` and `-0` options; the other doesn't work correctly if the names contain newlines (and that is a valid character in a Unix file name).  Similarly with the IFS hack.  Note that these are GNU-specific (though eminently sensible) extensions to the standard.

Comment: @Jonathan: I usually use `-d` myself just because it's less typing, and in practice filenames (at least for me) never contain newlines.  There's also the advantage that you can filter the output of `find` through other programs (grep, tail, etc) before sending it to `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the `-delete` option to `find`:

```
find . -name "*.exe" -delete
```

This saves you from quoting and any other filename hassles and is presumably faster than `-exec` because no new processes need to be spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Manually escaping the characters may help you.

```
find . -name "*.exe" | sed -s 's/\ /\\ /' | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: Not a reliable technique; all else apart, `xargs` splits names at blanks.  You might use `find . -name "*.exe" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`, where the `-print0` ends file names with ASCII NUL and the `-0` means that `xargs` reads names ending with ASCII NUL.  Note that these are GNU-specific (though eminently sensible) extensions to the standard.

Comment: @Jonathan True.. Your answer is definitely better.